# Vue.js value bind with prefix and suffix

Tags: html, vue.js, jscolor

I tried binding a value to an input using a variable that has been declared in the data object, but I also need to add a prefix and a suffix

```
<input id="topnavback", v-bind:value="rgb({{themestopnavback}})", class="jscolor"/>
```

The value themetopnavback is the value defined in data and I want to put the rgb with bracktes around it.

But this always causes the whole page not to render the DOM which only occurs if you try to access a Vue variable which isn't existing in the data object. Is this just wrong or isn't it possible to bind a value with additional strings?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just `rgb(themestopnavback)`?

Comment: That also won't let the DOM render...are you sure that vue should recognize that expression?

Comment: Is `rgb` defined on your Vue? Is `themestopnavback`? Show your Vue.

Comment: No, `themestopnavback` is defined there, not rgb. The value of `themestopnavback` only contains the numbers that needs to be in brackets  with the rgb in front of it. Also, my Vue is pretty big, I don't think it would make sense to post all of it here, but I defined it correctly, that's for sure.

Comment: Where is the `rgb` function defined? Is it just a string?

Comment: It's just a string. I just want the value attribute to get the content `"rgb(_value_of_themestopnavback)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
v-bind:value="'rgb(' + themestopnavback + ')'"
```